# Verifying periodicity of crystalline orbital modulus in PySCF

Tags: python, pyscf, orbitals, periodic-boundary-conditions

I'm trying to verify that the **modulus** of the crystalline atomic/molecular orbitals computed by PySCF satisfy the correct periodicity condition for the supercell. I'm considering a hydrogen chain oriented along the z-axis with H-H separation 1.0 and with two H atoms per cell, giving a cell size of 2.0.

The following code evaluates the modulus of the atomic/molecular orbitals for all k-points at positions $(0,0,0)$ and $(0,0,2)$.

One can see from the output of the code that they are far from equality. How can one understand this bizarre behavior?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from pyscf.pbc import gto, dft
from pyscf.pbc.dft import gen_grid, numint

num_kpts = 20

cell = gto.M(atom=[['H', (0.0, 0.0, 1.0)], ['H', (0.0, 0.0, 2.0)]],
             a=[[40.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0., 40.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 2.0]],
             verbose=1)


kpts = cell.make_kpts([1, 1, num_kpts])

mf = dft.KRKS(cell)
mf.kpts = kpts
mf.xc = 'lda,vwn'
mf = mf.density_fit()
energy = mf.kernel()

dm = cell.make_rdm1()

orbital_index = 0  # select an orbital for evaluation
points = [(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 2.0)]  # modulus should be equal at these points

print('orbital: ' + str(orbital_index))
for kpt_index in range(num_kpts):
    print('k-point: ' + str(kpt_index))
    kpt = kpts[kpt_index]
    ao = numint.eval_ao(cell, points, kpt=kpt) # (2, nao)
    rho = numint.eval_rho(cell, ao, dm).real # (2,)
    print('rho: ' + str(rho))
    ao_density = np.abs(ao[:, orbital_index])**2
    print('ao_density: ' + str(ao_density))
    mo_coeff = mf.mo_coeff  # (num_kpts, nao, nao)
    mo = np.einsum('xi,kij->xkj', ao, mo_coeff) # (2, num_kpts, nao)
    mo_density = np.abs(mo[:, kpt_index, orbital_index])**2
    print('mo_density: ' + str(mo_density))


# orbital: 0
# k-point: 0
# rho: [0.27688535 0.26870818]
# ao_density: [0.02243983 0.39680968]
# mo_density: [0.13844267 0.13435409]
# k-point: 1
# rho: [0.27400583 0.26613968]
# ao_density: [0.02186969 0.39587295]
# mo_density: [0.13927244 0.13514004]
# k-point: 2
# rho: [0.26569365 0.25872769]
# ao_density: [0.0202211  0.39316138]
# mo_density: [0.14179107 0.13752496]
# k-point: 3
# rho: [0.25287852 0.24730755]
# ao_density: [0.01767116 0.38895845]
# mo_density: [0.14608699 0.14159039]
# k-point: 4
# rho: [0.23695731 0.23313186]
# ao_density: [0.01448881 0.38369784]
# mo_density: [0.15230891 0.14747331]
# k-point: 5
# rho: [0.21960232 0.21769588]
# ao_density: [0.01100108 0.37791244]
# mo_density: [0.16066695 0.15536683]
# k-point: 6
# rho: [0.20255418 0.20255011]
# ao_density: [0.00755514 0.37217532]
# mo_density: [0.17143259 0.16551978]
# k-point: 7
# rho: [0.18743636 0.18913423]
# ao_density: [0.00448221 0.36704113]
# mo_density: [0.18493519 0.17823305]
# k-point: 8
# rho: [0.17561427 0.17865325]
# ao_density: [0.00206752 0.36299446]
# mo_density: [0.20155235 0.19385034]
# k-point: 9
# rho: [0.16810548 0.17200107]
# ao_density: [0.00052834 0.3604093 ]
# mo_density: [0.22168984 0.21274038]
# k-point: 10
# rho: [0.16553284 0.1697228 ]
# ao_density: [1.51068664e-28 3.59520862e-01]
# mo_density: [0.24574325 0.25196794]
# k-point: 11
# rho: [0.16810548 0.17200107]
# ao_density: [0.00052834 0.3604093 ]
# mo_density: [0.22168984 0.21274038]
# k-point: 12
# rho: [0.17561427 0.17865325]
# ao_density: [0.00206752 0.36299446]
# mo_density: [0.20155235 0.19385034]
# k-point: 13
# rho: [0.18743636 0.18913423]
# ao_density: [0.00448221 0.36704113]
# mo_density: [0.18493519 0.17823305]
# k-point: 14
# rho: [0.20255418 0.20255011]
# ao_density: [0.00755514 0.37217532]
# mo_density: [0.17143259 0.16551978]
# k-point: 15
# rho: [0.21960232 0.21769588]
# ao_density: [0.01100108 0.37791244]
# mo_density: [0.16066695 0.15536683]
# k-point: 16
# rho: [0.23695731 0.23313186]
# ao_density: [0.01448881 0.38369784]
# mo_density: [0.15230891 0.14747331]
# k-point: 17
# rho: [0.25287852 0.24730755]
# ao_density: [0.01767116 0.38895845]
# mo_density: [0.14608699 0.14159039]
# k-point: 18
# rho: [0.26569365 0.25872769]
# ao_density: [0.0202211  0.39316138]
# mo_density: [0.14179107 0.13752496]
# k-point: 19
# rho: [0.27400583 0.26613968]
# ao_density: [0.02186969 0.39587295]
# mo_density: [0.13927244 0.13514004]
```

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! Thank you for your contribution, and we hope to see much more of you in the future!!! I hope you decide to use a more recognizable name in the future, but it's not (yet) required.

Comment: Crystalline orbitals need not have the same periodicity as the cell - this is why we have to do k point sampling. What happens if you plot the total charge density? *That* should be periodic with  periodicity the length of the cell. However I'm not totally sure this is the case - your 2.0/3.657 is sufficiently close to the bohr <-> Angstrom conversion factor that there could just be a unit conversion problem. To be honest I doubt it as it's not that close, but plot the charge density to rule it out.

Comment: I think that the crystal orbitals should indeed have the periodicity of the cell (see Eq. 1 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.04832). Increasing the number of k-points to say 20 actually _increases_ the precision of the periodicity (updated code attached). I checked that the Angstrom/Bohr conversion does not explain the discrepancy. @IanBush

Comment: See https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/physical-interpretation-of-k-points and in particular "Note that a k-point component of the form 1/n, for any integer n, means that the wavefunction phase will be periodic with a period of nL. In other words, each rational k-point may be interpreted as an assumption that the wavefunction is periodic, but with period nL rather than L."

Comment: @IanBush I don't understand how that quote is consistent with the behavior of the code. I've updated the code above to check the mo_diff for all k-points and you can see that (with one notable exception) they are all periodic on a fixed interval of ~3.657

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really speak python (give me Fortran or C, or maybe Julia). It's just a fact from the maths that, as explained in the linked question, the orbitals need not have the same periodicity as the lattice. The fact it is fractional suggests a bug, but somone who knows the language will be a better person to take a look than I/

Comment: No worries @IanBush , but just worth noting  that the answer you linked to https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/physical-interpretation-of-k-points is discussing periodicity of the orbital whereas I am discussing periodicity of the absolute value of the orbital, which should indeed be periodic over an interval length $L$.

Comment: It's good to see so much conversation. If the comment chain gets to long though, it might need to get moved to the Python-based Matter Modeling room, or the Mathematics and Science of Matter Modeling room.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the `unit='Bohr'` flag in `gto.M` (as originally suggested in the comments) resolved the issue in the latest version of the code above.  Presumably there is a discrepancy in the default values of units passed to `numint` functions and `gto.M`.